# Subjunctive with "la seule fois"?

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif

The expressions *la première fois* and *la dernière fois* do [not](http://www.elearningfrench.com/french-course-2-lesson-9-grammar-2.html) take the subjunctive.

What about *la seule fois*?

> It was the only time I saw him.

Should it be

> C'était la seule fois que je l'ai vu.

or

> C'était la seule fois que je l'aie vu.

(Also, I'm not sure if we should use the present or past after the *que* here.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same rule, the event is real so there is no reason to use the subjunctive.

I would use the present and *passé composé*. You saw him once but you might see him again in the future:

> C'est la seule fois que je l'ai vu.

Or, if you really want to use the imperfect which leaves the possibility that you saw him later:

> C'était la seule fois où je l'avais vu.

or, using the *passé simple*. You saw him once and you'll never see him again. This is written/formal French:

> Ce fut la seule fois où je le vis.

Comment: Is it at least possible, though? What about: ["...c'est la seule fois que cet honneur ait été décerné à un pays."](http://www.parl.gc.ca/HousePublications/Publication.aspx?DocId=2974172&Language=F&Mode=1&Parl=39&Ses=1)

Comment: @LukeSawczak No, this sentence is imho incorrect. They should have written *c'est la seule fois que cet honneur a été décerné à un pays* or *ce fut la seule fois que cet honneur fut décerné à un pays.*

Comment: _C'était la seule fois **que** je l'avais vu_ est aussi possible. Je suis d'accord: "...c'est la seule fois que cet honneur ait été décerné à un pays." sonne incorrect.

Comment: _Ce fut la seule fois où je le vis._ est correct bien sûr, mais ces passés simples sont de moins en moins fréquents, à mon avis, surtout à l'oral.

Comment: @Frank C'est vrai, mais la question ne précise pas le registre.

Comment: Merci pour les précisions. J'ai upvoté.

Comment: Merci tous les deux.